# Ajax function working when running locally but when deployed in IIS it is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a ajax function like below in my MVC application

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '/UpdateDetail/GetlocationAjax',
         data: { cityId: cityId },
         dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {
          $.each(result, function (key, val) {
           workloc.append(
           $('<option></option>').val(val).html(key)
            );
          });
         },
         error: function (result) {
         }
         });
```

This work perfectly when i run the application from visual studio but when i deployed this in to IIS 7.5 this ajax function is not working

I tried the URL as `url: '../UpdateDetail/GetlocationAjax',` then the same not work at local level also but I have another application in which I call an ajax function as

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
         url: '../Preapproval/Getactivitycodetype',
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
                          $("#code_type-" + index)
         .append($('<option></option>').val("").html("--Type--")
                             );
                            $.each(result, function (key, val) {
                                $("#code_type-" + index).append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(val).html(key)
                                );
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                        }
                    });
```

This works in both local and IIS perfectly.

What can be the issue my first ajax function not work in IIS?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error? Is the error server side? Do you have any errors in browser console? Does it do not what you expect?

Comment: May not be the issue, but use `url: '@Url.Action("GetlocationAjax", "UpdateDetail")',` to unsure your urls are generated correctly

Comment: @dotnetom no error when a selectlist got change this ajax function will trigger and will fill another select list accordingly..but in IIS it is not filling the other select list. In local it is filling

Comment: @stephenmuecke thanks.. it worked..but can't understand why the second one work with out any problem..i used the same syntax for the first also.. please post it as answer i will mark it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetlocationAjax", "UpdateDetail")',
         data: { cityId: cityId },
         dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {
          $.each(result, function (key, val) {
           workloc.append(
           $('<option></option>').val(val).html(key)
            );
          });
         },
         error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
         }
         });
```

for this to work you have to keep the js, in cshtml page and not external js file because it is using MVC function `Url.Action()`;

If you want to keep the js in external file, then create a hidden field and read url from the hidden field like so

```
<input type="hidden" id="ajaxUrl" value='@Url.Action("GetlocationAjax", "UpdateDetail")' />
```

and then in your ajax call script use :

```
var url = $("#ajaxUrl").val();
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: url,
```

Also use chrom inspector to trace network request F12, network tab.